# Injected dependency is null

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, aurelia

Below are my two classes. Login and Activity. I want to inject Login into Activity. This occurs after Login has already been executed and parameters set. In file 2, login.UserName is always undefined and any other items I try to bind are undefined. Is there any thing that I am missing for proper binding?

```
//file 1
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'fetch';

@autoinject
export class Login{
    @bindable UserName:String

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
        ...redacted...
    }

    login(){
       this.UserName="test";
    }
}


//file 2
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import 'fetch';
import {Login} from 'login/src/login';

@autoinject
export class Activity {
    Login: Login;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private login: Login) {
      ...redacted...
      this.Login=login;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Activity` class / custom-element is being injected with a different instance of the `Login` class / custom-element.  Although the items are typically have container-controlled "singleton" lifetimes, UI components don't.  I think you could get what you have to work by adding the `@singleton` to your `Login` ui component but you might be better off creating a separate class, possibly called "User" that you can inject into both the `Login` UI component and the `Activity` UI component.

Comment: This was exactly right. I for some reason though UI components were singletons also...which is silly in hindsight. I separated into a separate class and works like a dream, thanks!